# Filter throws - Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I am trying to filter on the given input against the cached query result. Since I am filtering again user input value and database , I am converting them in to lower case and checking

```
result =  this.cachedResults.filter(f => f.prj.toLowerCase().indexOf((this.sV).toLowerCase()) !== -1);
```

It works fine until the cachedResult dont have `NULL` in that field. But if there is NULL how can I escape that record here.

Comment: Is the error complaining about `f.prj.toLowerCase()` or about `(this.sV).toLowerCase()`?

Comment: @rickdenhaan `f.prj.toLowerCase()` as the f.prj has sometimes NULL value in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `f.prj` is `NULL` then it cannot contain `this.sV` so that particular `f` should be filtered out, correct? In that case:

```js
result = this.cachedResults.filter(f => f.prj && f.prj.toLowerCase().indexOf((this.sV).toLowerCase()) !== -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You got to check if the property `prj` exists in your object before using `toLowerCase()` on it.

```
result =  this.cachedResults.filter(f => {
  return f.prj ? (f.prj.toLowerCase().indexOf((this.sV).toLowerCase()) !== -1) : false
});
```

Does this work for you?

If the problem is that `(this.sV)` does not exist, then you'll have to check that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like following to catch the null value in `f.prj`:

```
result =  this.cachedResults.filter(f => { 
    if (!f.prj) {
        return false; // Or return true, if you want
    }
    return f.prj.toLowerCase().indexOf((this.sV).toLowerCase()) !== -1);
});
```